# How to select the last n items from a list in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I would need to store a removed item from a list (`list 1`) into a new one (`list 2`) and select the last `n` items from this list. Lists' maximum length is `10`, but there could be less items stored there.
Items are stored using `fput`, so they are from the newest to the oldest. 
To remove the oldest item, that I would like to add into the `list 2`, I am using the following lines of code:

```
           if length list_1 > 10 [
            set list_1 but-last list_1 print "The item is removed"
          ]
```

and I would like to add this item into `list_2`. Once I have more than 3 items in the `list_2`, I would like to select `n` (e.g. `1`) of the last items added to it.

Do you have any idea on how I can do that?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [`sublist`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/subliststring.html)  is probably easiest here- use it to subset from your n-index, as "length of the list - n", to the length of your list.

```
globals [ list1 list2 ]

to setup
  ca
  set list1 ( range 1 11 )
  set list2 []
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  let n 3

  print ( word "List 1:\n" list1 "\n" )

  if not empty? list1 [
    set list2 lput last list1 list2
    set list1 but-last list1
  ]

  if length list2 > 3 [
    let list2Sublist sublist list2 ( length list2 - n ) ( length list2 ) 
    print ( word "List 2 sublist:\n" list2Sublist "\n" )
  ]

  tick
end
```

Hopefully that gets you in the right direction!